# Powershell Search Automation - GetElementbyID won't return values for controls created with Javascript

Tags: javascript, powershell

I'm working on a project to automate the search of tax records on a county website. Eventually, I want to be able to give Powershell a list of ID numbers and have it return results for all those numbers. The code I have so far is here:

```
#Open IE and go to www.gastontax.com
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://www.gastontax.com/")
$ie.visible = $true

#Yield the script while the page is loading
While ( $ie.busy -eq $true){
[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(200)
}

#Set the document and the frames
$doc = $ie.document
$frames = $doc.frames

#Accept the notification
$btn = $doc.getElementByID("ctl00_Tax_btnAccept")
$btn.click()

#Yield the script while the page is loading
While ( $ie.busy -eq $true){
[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(200)
}

#Create the drop-down search parameters
$taxyear = "All"
$status = "Unpaid"
$searchtype = "Both"
$searchparam = "Parcel Number"
$searchtext = "XXXXXX"

#Set the drop-down search parameters
$doc.getElementbyID("ctl00_Tax_drpTaxYear").value = $taxyear
$doc.getElementbyID("ctl00_Tax_drpStatus").value = $status
$doc.getElementbyID("ctl00_Tax_drpSearchType").value = $searchtype
$doc.getElementbyID("ctl00_Tax_drpSearchParam").value = $searchparam

#Create the parcel name parameter
$doc.getElementbyID("ctl00_Tax_txtSearchParam").value = $searchtext

$btn2 = $doc.getElementByID("ctl00_Tax_btnSearch")
$btn2.click()
```

However, whenever I try to set the values of the controls, I get the following message for each of the getElementbyID lines:

> The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

I noticed that the values I'm looking for--"ctl00_Tax_drpTaxYear", "ctl00_Tax_drpStatus", etc.--do not exist in the page's source code until *after* I hit the button on the welcome page (marked by $btn.click()). Could this have something to do with the error Powershell is throwing? If so, how would I get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Search param appears to be a textbox. You way want to try .text instead of .value

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan: The [Internet Explorer COM Automation interface](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa752084) uses `.value` as an abstraction even for text input fields. By contrast, `.text` is not a supported property. The only issue at hand is that `$ie.Document` doesn't reflect the _reloaded_ DOM after the first button click.

Answer (score 0):

I could only get it to work with a *hack* involving strategic toggling of the visibility of IE (Internet Explorer), which appears to be necessary for the DOM to be fully reflected in `$ie.Document` (see comments in source code below).

The hack seems to work reliably on my Windows 10 machine with IE 11, but YMMV.

Generally:

- The [Internet Explorer COM Automation interface](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa752084) is obsolescent, so it's worth considering an alternative, such as [Edge's WebDriver support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/webdriver-commands/) (an entirely different technology that [*may* become a W3C standard](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html)).
- Sticking with the IE COM object, the hack *may* not be necessary if [DOM-related *events*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa752084) are used instead, but I'm not sure if they're supported in PowerShell.

---

```
# Helper function for wating until a condition is true.
function await([scriptblock] $sb) {
  while (-not (& $sb)) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200 }
}

$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://www.gastontax.com/")

# Wait until the page has finished loading.
await { $ie.ReadyState -eq 4 }

# Click the "Yes, I accept" button.
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_Tax_btnAccept").click()

# !! HACK (part 1 of 2):
# !! Delaying making IE visible until here seems to be the only way
# !! to get the new DOM to be at least *partially* reflected in $ie.document.
$ie.visible = $true

# Wait until the page has finished loading.
await { $ie.ReadyState -eq 4 }

# !! HACK (part 2 of 2):
# !! Inexplicably, another toggling of visibility is what it takes for *all* 
# !! elements in the new DOM to be accessible via $ie.Document.
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.visible = $true

#Create the drop-down search parameters
$taxyear = "All"
$status = "Unpaid"
$searchtype = "Both"
$searchparam = "Parcel Number"
$searchtext = "XXXXXX"

#Set the drop-down search parameters
$doc = $ie.document
$doc.getElementById("ctl00_Tax_drpTaxYear").value = $taxyear
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_Tax_drpStatus").value = $status
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_Tax_drpSearchType").value = $searchtype
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_Tax_drpSearchParam").value = $searchparam

#Create the parcel name parameter
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_Tax_txtSearchParam").value = $searchtext

$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_Tax_btnSearch").click()
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. However, for some reason, it still trips up on "ctl00_Tax_drpTaxYear". And even weirder, if I try to run it multiple times in the same instance of Powershell, the rest of the variables don't work consecutive times.

Comment: @JasonLecker: Please see my update. It now works reliably for me, perhaps it will for you too, but it's still a hack. I've deleted my original comment and added the information about alternatives to the answer.